# Calculate distribution of a random variable using characteristic function

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable such that its characteristic function is

$$\varphi_X(t)=e^{-|t|} \qquad \forall t \in \mathbb R$$

Calculate its distribution function.

**My attempt at a solution:**

The integral $$\int_{- \infty} ^{\infty} |\varphi_X(t)| \,dt$$ it's finite. So $X$ is absolutely continuous and, fixed $x \in \mathbb R$ , it's distribution function calculated in $x$ is equal to

\begin{align}
f_X(x)  &= \frac{1} {2\pi} \int_{- \infty} ^{\infty} e^{-itx} \varphi_X(t)\,dt \\
       &= \frac{1} {\pi} \int_{0} ^{\infty} e^{-itx} e^{-t} \,dt
 \\ 
       &= \frac{1} {\pi} \int_{0} ^{\infty} \cos(tx) e^{-t} \,dt
        - i \frac{1} {\pi} \int_{0} ^{\infty} \sin(tx) e^{-t} \,dt  
\\ 
       &= \frac{1} {\pi} \frac {1}  {1+x^2}
        - i \frac{1} {\pi} \frac {x}  {1+x^2} \\        
\end{align}

**But** the solution of the book is:

$$ f_X(x) = \frac{1} {\pi} \frac {1}  {1+x^2} $$

So **my doubt is**: why the imaginary part disappears?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in line 2 of your proof. The integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$  is twice the integral form $0$ to $\infty$ for even functions. For odd functions the integral is actually $0$. So  integral of $\sin (tx) \phi_X (t)$ is $0$.